# Activity not launch click on FCM push notification when app killed by user or App in background

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, push-notification, background

I'm setting up FCM push-notification and When I'm kill app or background app and notification generate then Notification generated when i'm click on notification then app not open also no any log error given by Firebase.

Notification generate through rest api post requests to firebase backend.

I have also check via FCM Notification Quick Project same problem occurs.

Note :-> A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.Here this is not working once default activity open then i will get data from system tray.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/765

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded

Answer (score 0):

```
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0; 

private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        PendingIntent contentIntent = null;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        Random random = new Random();
        NOTIFICATION_ID = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: when app in background or kill by user and user click on notification then onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
this method not call and you have provided code put inside onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) method this is not worked
this code work when app is open and user click on notification but i don't need this